# Import csv file through a shell script

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, shell

Is Importing a csv file through a shell script a good idea? Why yes and why not? What are the principal issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you approach it, I have on many occasions had no choice but to import CSV via a shell script - files coming from third party sources that cant be practical to split up.

Formats that are from non technical clients and not able to get them to put it into a format that the Magento Data importer works.

Writing a custom importer is relatively easy but you need to ensure you can handle error conditions in a sensible way. You also will need to ensure that all of the data attributes are pre-defined , or that you are able to create them on the during the import process.

**Benefits**

- Import can work with any CSV (you would have to define the import script)
- Fast Import can be achieved if bypassing Magento API and using SQL direct.
- Can enable you to programatically generate your attributes/values on the fly.

**Disadvantages**

- Requires Custom Logic
- Risk of not importing all required information for proper operation of Magento (eg stock control)
- No clear strategy for handling data - you need to define it properly.
- By passing Magento API would require solid understanding of database structure.
- Might break in future updates.
- Updates from CSV might not be feasible - you might need to custom track between old and new ie if its a 3rd party and they delete the product how to identify that it should be deleted on next import.

There are some alternatives out there that I would reccomend you consider investigating before deciding that writing your own custom CSV importer is the correct strategy for your requirements. I have outlined two of the popular options below.

**Magmi**

Magmi is a mass importer for Magento, quite popular although it does have some bugs so it may not work for every senario. I've recently used it on a project and we had to disable some import functionality (to do with categories) because it broke price importing.

See More: http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/

**API Import**

It might not be using a CSV to do an import, but I think it might be worth considering. It was mentioned at a recent conference which I went to the author being a presenter. I think you will need to do a bit of pre import leg work to get it to the right setup but you can be fairly sure it will import correctly.

See More: https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport

Comment: Thanks John!

What would be a clear data handling strategy?

What are the serious concerns to take into consideration?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about Magento shell scripts. You can achieve exactly the same functions with Magento shell scripts as you would with a proper extension if you just want to import CSV data. You use the same Magento methods.

I only see a few advantages of using Magento shell script including but not limited to:

1. You can schedule it with the system cron, allowing you to avoid interrupting Magento cron jobs if the CSV import take a long time.
2. No need to configure an extension.

The only time I use a shell script is when I'm migrating data (products, orders, etc.), or when there's a cron job that I know is intensive and takes up a lot of time, like bulk product creation/update, stock update, order syncing, etc.

With these kind of integrations, I usually create an extension that has all of the business logic and create shell scripts as entry points to the extension's processes. That way I can package my program properly and have it accessible by the system to be run independent of the Magento cron jobs.

Comment: Do you mean that shell import is a better alternative for a cron job that's too intensive?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I believe intensive Magento cron jobs configured in `config.xml` will hold up and cancel other queued cron jobs (depends system configuration) if it takes too long. I haven't verified in the latest versions (CE 1.9/EE 1.14), but it was the case previously.